# how to specify image dimension/size when doing a drawAtPoint?

Tags: ios, uiimage, drawing, draw, redraw

I have some images and I want to draw them using `drawAtPoint` ( I am using a table of 100s of cells and doing the draw as recommended for making the scrolling faster). Now, these images are kind of random (their size can be anything.. ) and I need to specify the dimension I want to fit in.

Can anyone kindly tell me what to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find the recommendation to draw images this way btw? Just interested, as I use the cells subviews in most cases.

Comment: @SideSwipe : apple tableview suits no.5 and stackoverflow....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want to do use:

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

When using drawAtPoint you cannot specify the dimensions, it will draw the entire image in the current graphics context.